# Store informations about ERC1155 tokens - Solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I want to store informations about ERC1155 tokens AND use it in same contract. Best way for me is get information from token metadata, but i don't know how to do this, I found only function to get token URI but i can't read informations from metadata

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like this is a job for storage variables. A mapping, to be precise.

You could define a mapping that maps each token id to a struct that contains its data like this:

```
struct NftData {
  ... // Insert NFT data params here
}

mapping(uint256 => NftData) public nftData;
```

Comment: thanks, but I have 10k tokens, everyone with diffrent params, how to store it in structs? Can I put data from metadata to struct?